# I.D number generator

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, generator

so basically i got an assignment to create a generator that will produce valid I.D numbers for citizans in my country.
a valid number is 9 digits, for each digit you need to multiply it by 1 or 2 according to the index, if the index is even, multiply the num by 1, else multiply it by 2.
after that if a curtain digit became greater than 9, change it to the sum of its digits. 
if the overall sum % 10 == 0 then the num is valid.
else false.

after that they wanted me to create a class that will produce an itirator.
in the **next** method:
if the number that was  given is valid, return it and multiply afterwards by 2 and add 1, and then check again if valid or not, if not multiply by 2 and add 2 and so on..
if from the beginning the num wasn't valid, multiply by 2 and add 1 then multiply by 2 and add 2 and so on...

```
import string
letters = string.ascii_letters
digits = string.digits


class NumNotNineLong(Exception):

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
        return "The number you provided is not nine digits long."

class NotNumber(Exception):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __str__(self):
        return "The input you provided is not an integer"

class IDIterator():

    increment = 1

    def __init__(self,_id):
        self._id = _id  

    def __iter__(self):
       return self 

    def __next__(self):

        while check_id_valid(str(self._id)[-9::]) == False:
            self._id *= 2
            self._id += IDIterator.increment
            IDIterator.increment += 1
        if check_id_valid(str(self._id)[-9::]):
            result = str(self._id)[-9::]
            self._id *= 2
            self._id += 1
            IDIterator.increment = 2
            return result



def check_id_valid(id_number):
    for letter in str(id_number):
        if letter not in string.digits:
            raise NotNumber
    numbers = [int(i) for i in str(id_number)]
    if len(numbers) != 9:
        raise NumNotNineLong
    set_numbers = []
    for i in range(len(numbers)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            set_numbers.append(numbers[i])
        else:
            set_numbers.append(numbers[i] * 2)
    true_numbers = []
    for num in set_numbers:
        if num > 9:
            temp = [int(i) for i in str(num)]
            true_numbers.append(sum(temp))
        else:
            true_numbers.append(num)
    if sum(true_numbers) % 10 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def main():
    result = IDIterator(123456780)
    for _ in range(10):
        print(result.__next__())




if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

my results are :

```
209872373
274495985
097983944
391935780
903409134
227273083
545477432
363819467
910555747
409086964
```

wanted results are:

```
209872373
863664504
569826803
339640302
473959864
544578024
356624288
466187762
040830960
487293938
```

save me

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My take on the problem:

```
class IDIterator:
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.__num = num

    def __iter__(self):
        n, num = 1, self.__num
        while True:
            num = int( str(num)[-9:] )
            if is_valid(num):
                yield '{:0>9}'.format(num)
                num *= 2
                num += n
                n = 1
            else:
                num *= 2
                num += n
                n += 1

def is_valid(num):
    s = '{:0>9}'.format(num)

    if len(s) != 9:
        return False

    nums = [int(ch) * 2 if i % 2 else int(ch) for i, ch in enumerate(s)]
    nums = [sum(int(c) for c in str(n)) for n in nums]
    return sum(nums) % 10 == 0

from itertools import islice

for num in islice(IDIterator(123456780), 0, 10):
    print(num)
```

Prints:

```
209872373
863664504
569826803
339640302
473959864
544578024
356624288
466187762
040830960
487293938
```

Comment: it seems that you have a mistake with the last 2 results.

Comment: @DarkLeader Yes, i posted it into the comments. Are you sure your expected results are correct?

Comment: those are the results i was given. i think i know why you got the mistake. you didn't consider having a number that starts with 0 so when you used int() on it you lost the "0" i fixed it anyways. i got the correct results! thank you!